# openni_tracker and OS X (again)

Tags: openi-tracker, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I reported in another question, if I try to rosmake openni_kinect on my snow leopard system, openni_tracker fails, saying that is can't find a bunch of files:

```
error: XnOpenNI.h: No such file or directory
```

But these files all seem to be in the openni binaries I installed in another directory on my computer.

How do I tell openni_kinect where those files are?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9787/openni_tracker-and-os-x-(again)/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-12**:
Could you re-title the headline into a question? I'm hoping to set a trend to make questions easier to browse. Something like "How do you get ROS to find OpenN includes in OS X?" perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Odds are pretty good it's a path problem.

Make sure that your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH include the OpenNI stuff.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1